# How to refresh facebook scrape cache for a whole site

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to re-scrape facebook's cache for every page in my web site (3000+ pages)
The only way i know how to do that is too tough [Open graph debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

I Cannot run this with 3000...

I read From Facebook developer support page that this (StackOverflow) is the place to ask questions but there is **little to none knowledge** about refreshing facebook url cache

Can you please suggest any working solution to re-scrape a page?

my web site: [Mentallica](http://www.mentallica.co.il)

Comment: anyone? facebook know how?

Comment: Why no one answering this? is there any developers in Facebook corp. that have any clue ??? please help, i'm stuck with this issue for the last half year

Answer (score 0):

3 years later, but this can help someone: Paste yout url here and click fetch new scrape information: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer, given the number of URL's you've got, is to use the batch invalidator. You could go to an access list of your URL's, or maybe do a recursive directory listing and replace the folders with URL's (if it's a flat site), or the like. At least, you don't have to do them one at a time. Once you have a list, paste the list into the invalidator (multiple lines).

The batch invalidator is here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/batch/

It IS frustrating. I've searched several places, and don't really see a solution. We have a website with all of the proper tags, yet FB refuses to refresh any past posts with the new website data.